# Forms Authentication using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, formsauthentication

Hope someone has had this experience and found a way. Thanks in advance for your input and help.

I have an ASP.NET web application with typical Forms Authentication infrastructure in place. Login page is declared in web.config, etc. Everything works well. Recently, I have run into a situation where I need to allow someone to log in, in an unobtrusive way, while filling out a particular form on the site. I have been trying to do this via jquery and ajax by presenting a hidden div login form that requests a server side page which, in turn, communicates with the same business layer class/methods that the typical login page uses. This much does work. The user gets a seamless login experience without leaving the current form being filled out. Chrome shows that auth cookie is created. Seems great.

The problem: After logging in via ajax as described above, if the user goes to the site's typical web form login page, they are asked to log in. I am trying to make it so the ajax log in will actually log the user in - the same way as the typical web form does.

Not even sure it's possible. I've been beaten up with it for a couple of days. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.